# T test 3D array

Tags: arrays, r, t-test

I have a 3D array of data defined by `[i,j,k]` and want to perform a single sample t-test on the 3rd dimension, `[k]`, testing for difference from 0. Ideally, the results would be returned as a matrix of t values of size `[i,j]`. Unfortunately, I do not know the size of the 3D array beforehand.

```
set.seed(1999)
i <- 4; j <- 2; k <- 6
df <- runif((i*j*k))
ar <- array(df, c(i, j, k))
```

Comment: Could you clarify? The dimensions of an array is simply that, a dimension. You will be wanting to test data within and array, so it needs to have some defining scope...if you say k with no other dimension, then it is 6 planes deep, do you want the data from all six planes of 4 by 2 tested, all the data?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, try the following.

```
tt <- apply(ar, 1:2, t.test)
apply(tt, 1, function(x) lapply(x, identity))
```